# System.Object type which is not supported by PBI (Power BI)service

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have set Azure Stream Analytic job output as Power BI. But I am getting warning in the analytic job that **System.Object type which is not supported by PBI service.**

Also I am not able to see any data in Power BI . But I can see the database created there which ensure that stream analytic job output is coming there.

Below is the sample data sent to Power BI. I know the error happens because one of the property is an object .  Is there any thing I can do at Power BI to handle this?

```
{"test":
{"name":"testApp",
"date":"2015-07-31T10:38:45.1276956+05:30",
"flag":true,
"val":"2015-07-31T10:38:45.1276956+05:30",
"var":"123","231":1},
"cmd":"123",
"root":"123123",
"result":61116}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle this scenario , we need to modify the stream analytics query.

For the above the sample query will as follow,

> SELECT **test**.name,**test**.date,**test**.flag,cmd,root,result into
>   [streamanalyticsoutput] from [streamanalyticsinput]

streamanalyticsoutput -- will be the power bi output alias

streamanalyticsinput -- event hub input