# Linq select into a new class without Group

Tags: c#, linq

Will it be possible to write linq to put result into some other object without using group like below,

```
SELECT test.name, test.date, test.flag, cmd, root, result
into [streamanalyticsoutput] from [streamanalyticsinput]
```

Here is the Linq query with Group,

```
var query2 = from c in _context.MCTargets
             group c by c.MarketingCampaignID into g
             select new 
             {
                 StartDate = d1,
                 EndDate = d2
             };
```

Comment: "some other object"? What do you mean?

Comment: into "g" like above or into [streamanalyticsoutput], but without group

Comment: Do you only want to select specific fields?

Comment: may be all or some specific fieds

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Why are you using group by in the first place...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your sql there is no need for grouping at all - just a projection to a different type of object

```
var result = from c in _context.MCTargets
             select new {
                 // Project here only the fields you want from the MCTargets
                 Name = c.Name,
                 Date = c.Date,
                 Flag = c.Flag
             };
```

In this case it is just projecting into an anonymous type but if you have a specific class then use `select new YourClass { ... }`

Comment: true, but wanted to put same result into some other variable and hen select

Comment: @user584018 - what do you mean by same result?

Comment: from c in _context.MCTargets into Xyz, then select from Xyz

Comment: What is the purpose of what you are trying to do?

Comment: wanted to something like this,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738952/system-object-type-which-is-not-supported-by-pbi-power-biservice

Comment: @user584018 - that is why I'm trying to understand what you want to do - because you can probably do it in the first query

Comment: How to do what?

Answer (score 1):

This will select all fields:

```
var query2 = (from c in _context.MCTargets
              select c).ToList();
```

You can then use as many properties of the `MCTarget` object that you want.

If only want to select some columns for some reason, you could create anonymous objects:

```
var query2 = (from c in _context.MCTargets
              select new { Name = c.Name, Date = c.Date}).ToList();
```

...or you could create a new class and set the properties of this one:

```
var query2 = (from c in _context.MCTargets
              select new YourClass { Name = c.Name, Date = c.Date}).ToList();
```

Comment: You don't have to specify `Name = c.Name` and `Date = c.Date`. You only need to specify names when you want the anonymous object to have different property names than the source.

Comment: Well, the names of the properties were just sample names. Maybe bad sample names but still just samples :)